# Pivot pandas dataframe to get resultant dataframe in correct order

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have an excel data in below format:

```
    Original Data Frame
    Package FISCAL_YR   SCENARIO    PERIOD   USD_AMT     LY_USD_AMT      CY_NetSales     LY_NetSales 
    Canada  2021            Plan    Per01    1.00            2.00            3.00            4.00 
    Africa  2021            Actual  Per04    1.00            2.00            3.00            4.00 
    Africa  2021            Actual  Per09    1.00            2.00            3.00            4.00 
    Brazil  2021            Plan    Per11    1.00            2.00            3.00            4.00 
    Brazil  2021            Actual  Per05    1.00            2.00            3.00            4.00 
    Africa  2021            Actual  Per07    1.00            2.00            3.00            4.00 
    Mexico  2021            Plan    Per10    1.00            2.00            3.00            4.00 
    Canada  2021            Actual  Per02    1.00            2.00            3.00            4.00
```

In order to ease out my calculations, i am trying to get the values in scenario column to header with values from the last 4 columns to be appropriately assigned:

```
    Expected dataframe:
                                                                                            
                                                Actual                                                              Plan            
    Package   Sum of USD_AMT    Sum of LY_USD_AMT   Sum of CY_NetSales  Sum of LY_NetSales  Sum of USD_AMT  Sum of LY_USD_AMT   Sum of CY_NetSales  Sum of LY_NetSales
    Africa          3           6                           9                   12              
    Brazil          2           4                           6                   8               
    Canada          1           2                           3                   4                   1                   2                   3                   4
    Mexico          1           2                           3                   4
```

I am trying the Pivot table option for this in pandas but it is rending the below output:

Failed Solution:

```
pd_piv=pd.pivot_table(df_dummy,index=['Package', 'FISCAL_YR', 'PERIOD'], 
                      columns=['SCENARIO'],
                      values=['USD_AMT', 'LY_USD_AMT', 'CY_NetSales', 'LY_NetSales'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
pd_piv.head()

            CY_NetSales         LY_NetSales         LY_USD_AMT          USD_AMT     
        SCENARIO    Actual  Plan    WRKG_FCST   Actual  Plan    WRKG_FCST   Actual  Plan    WRKG_FCST   Actual  Plan    WRKG_FCST
Package_SubCategory FISCAL_YR_NBR   FISCAL_PERIOD_NBR
```

*numbers are not shown since the actual data is quite different

Is there anyway to get the above shown expected dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:
1- Make your pivot table:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data={"package":["Canada","Africa","Africa","Brazil","Brazil","Africa","Mexico","Canada"],
"scenario":["Plan","Actual","Actual","Plan","Actual","Actual","Plan","Actual"],
"USD_AMT":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,],
"LY_USD_AMT":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)


pd_piv=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['package'],
                  columns=['scenario'],
                  values=['USD_AMT', 'LY_USD_AMT',], aggfunc=np.sum,fill_value=0)
```

Result:

```
         LY_USD_AMT      USD_AMT
scenario     Actual Plan  Actual Plan
package
Africa            3    0       3    0
Brazil            1    1       1    1
Canada            1    1       1    1
Mexico            0    1       0    1
```

2- swap the index levels:

```
pd_piv.columns=pd_piv.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
pd_piv.sort_index(axis=1, level=0, inplace=True)
```

Final result:

```
scenario     Actual               Plan
         LY_USD_AMT USD_AMT LY_USD_AMT USD_AMT
package
Africa            3       3          0       0
Brazil            1       1          1       1
Canada            1       1          1       1
Mexico            0       0          1       1
```